# What is a && (a || b) equivalent to?

Tags: boolean, logic

A. true

B. a

C. a || !b

D. !a || b

Can someone explain to me?
Thanks

Comment: Have you learnt discrete math before? Or do you understand law of transitivity and so on?

Comment: @user3437460 did not know I need that to do this ...

Comment: If you want a convincing reply and deep explanation, I would suggest you posting this question at http://math.stackexchange.com Mathematicians can probably teach you better than a asking a programmer. Not that you need to know those stuff, but you can solve it in a few seconds if you know those.

Comment: If a is false the && is false too. If a is true the first part of the && is true and since true || something is also true the second part is true. For this reason it is true if a is true and false if it is false. Which means the right solution is B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since && and || are [short circuit operators](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html)

```
if a = true // output is true
if a = false // output is false
```

So, `B:a` is the answer